# Django passing parameter with AJAX

Tags: django, django-views, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass parameters to Django view but I couldn't decide what is the best way to do it.

I am making an AJAX call and my javascript code is

```
url = "/review/flag/code/"+ code +"/type/" + type + "/content/" + content + "/";
$.getJSON(url, somefunction);
```

The corresponding url for this call

```
(r'^rate/code/(?P<code>[-\w]+)/type/(?P<type>[-\w]+)/content/(?P<content>[-\w]+)/$', 'project.views.flag_review'),
```

And I can get the parameters in my view such that

```
def rate_review(request,code,type,content):
    ....
```

My question is because `content` comes from a `textarea` it may involve many escape chars and passing it like above causes problems due to regular expression.

Is there any way if I pass the parameters like www.xx.com/review/rate?code=1&type=2&content=sdfafdkaposdfkapskdf... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `content` variable is input through a `textarea` input field in a form, you should probably be using the HTTP `POST` method for submitting the data.  You would get something like:

```
 url = "/review/flag/code/"+ code +"/type/" + type;
 $.post(url, {'content': content}, somefunction, 'html');

 (r'^rate/code/(?P<code>[-\w]+)/type/(?P<type>[-\w]+)/$', 'project.views.flag_review'),

def rate_review(request,code,type):
    content = request.POST['content']
    ...
```

Comment: It's good answer thanks but I am using method like $.getJSON(url,{ content:reason },somefunction);  instead $.post . How can I achive passing parameter as post method in Jquery getJSON function ?

Comment: I found this : Since there is no $.postJSON, if you are doing a jQuery ajax post and expecting a JsonResult, you must always pass ‘json’ as the fourth parameter to $.post.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, in your `rate_review` function you can access `request.GET` and access those paramters:

```
/rate/code/?foo=bar

def rate_review(request):
    request.GET['foo']
```